# System.OutOfMemoryException when trying to run a create table script generated by SQL Server Management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, mscorlib

i've 8GB of ram, when i tried it on a 16GB machine the script runs fine, all it does is it creats 2 tables and fills them with data, about 12000 records for each table and 38 columns for the first table and 18 columns for the second table.

the script was generated by sql manager studio 2012 it self and the size of the script is about 78MB.

how can i run it on 8GB machine without getting an out of memory exception?

the script has an Insert command for each record.

its seems to be a know issue and yet microsoft doesn't have fix http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/269566/sql-server-management-studio-cant-handle-large-files

all i did split the script to smaller pieces and it worked fine on the 8GB machine.

Comment: I'd give this bug a low priority too. If you want to migrate a lot of data the easiest and fastest way is to export them using `bcp` and import them to the new table. Bulk inserts also cause minimal logging, which is very important if you have a lot of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is running fine on a `16 GB` machine, you can try increasing the `virtual memory` of your own machine. But that could result in longer execution time of your script.

Instead, you should consider increasing RAM of your own machine.

To increase VM of your machine, go to

> System properties->Advanced->Performance->Settings->Advanced->Virtual
>   Memory->Change